# i am using api add post in wordpress

Tags: json

i will use below link to add post in my WordPress
[enter link description here](https://myfundbox.com/webhook?listByProjectId=6)

```
   this is the link for JSON data
```

this my code :-

$reddit_data = wp_remote_get( 'https://myfundbox.com/webhook?listByProjectId=6' );

$reddit_data_decode = json_decode( $reddit_data['body'] );

foreach ( $reddit_data_decode->prodList as $item ) {
$post_title    = $item->DBUrl; // post title
$reddit_author = $item->CollectedAmount; // author
$up_votes      = $item->CollectedAmount; // up votes
//   print_r($post_title);
//   die();

```
// for the create a some post
 $my_post = array(
    'post_title'  => $post_title,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
 );
```

when ever i refresh the page its will add every time new post:-
my wish to add post if there not post or if there are already a registered post then don't want to add post in my post

can anyone help me please why my code add every time post current i have more then 10000+ post

Comment: "why my code add every time post" - because you've told it to add all the posts and haven't written any code to stop adding duplicates? Is the title unique, i.e. before you add a post you could check if any posts already exist with the same title? If one does exist, did you want to update the post instead? I don't think WordPress has an 'insert or update' for posts, sorry, at least by title - so you'll have to write some logic yourself.

Comment: Alternatively is there a way to solve this with your API, e.g. asking it to only return new posts since the last time you ran an update?